# How can I convert a string to a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

look at the code

```
var string = "0,1";
var array = [string];
alert(array[0]);
```

In this case, alert would pop-up a 0,1. When it would be an array, it would pop-up a 0, and when alert(array[1]); is called, it should pop-up the 1.

Is there any chance to convert such string into a JavaScript array?

Comment: You can use the split property.

Answer (score 0):

Try split property;

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

If an empty string ('') is used as the separator, the string is split between each character.

```
 str = "asdasfasfa";
 list = str.split(''); //list = ["a", "s", "d", "a", "s", "f", "a", "s", "f", "a"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`var string = "0,1";
var array = [string];
alert(array[0]);`

1. this methods get a array of number element

`string.split(',').map(item=>+item);//[1,2]`

2. this methods get a array of string element

`string.split(',');//['1','2']`

3. convert a string to array can use Array.from

`Array.from('1,23')//['1',',','2','3']`

[string methods in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)